# Chef: creating secret file before reading databag

Tags: chef-infra

I am trying to use encrypted data bags but i am in trouble.
I wrote a recipe which copy the secret file to the node. Then the needed values in the databag should be unencrypted with that secret.
It seems that variables are processed before the secret is copied so i got an error like

> No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /etc/chef/mysql_db_keys/mysql-secret

see code below :

```rb
cookbook_file '/etc/chef/mysql_db_keys/mysql-secret' do
  source 'mysql-secret'  
  owner 'root'  
  group 'root'  
  mode '0700' 
end

root = data_bag_item('OX-db','root_account',IO.read('/etc/chef/mysql_db_keys/mysql-secret')) 
rootpass = root['password']

template "/data/install/CreateAdminAccounts.sql" do
  source "CreateAdminAccounts.sql.erb"
  variables( root_password: "#{rootpass}"   )
  owner "root"
  group "root"   
  mode "0600"   
  sensitive true 
end
```

Is there a way to copy secret file before interpreting variables ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found better approach to manage this with chef vault :

https://www.chef.io/blog/2016/01/21/chef-vault-what-is-it-and-what-can-it-do-for-you/

Comment: Link only answers are not really welcome on stackoverflow (as if the link break, there's no answer anymore). Please consider quoting the relevant paragraph in your answer so people can have an idea of what it is about without clicking the link.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't distribute the bag decryption key via Chef. That defeats the whole point of using encrypted bags in the first place (i.e. that the Chef Server can't read the data). You'll need to implement something out of band to Chef to manage and distribute keys. `knife bootstrap` has a very simple version of this where it copies over the key from your workstation to the target at bootstrap time, but this is unlikely to be all you need in the long run.